# Remove all instance of a string and 3 digit number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex to remove any instance of a string that includes 3 numbers that I do not know.

For example, if the string was `this is an example536 string with 2 example725`, I want "example536" and "example725" to be removed.

I know the basics of regex to get rid of "example" but have no idea how to get rid of the digits. Could someone please help with this.

Comment: Depending on the type of regex syntax, your search might be something like `\w+\d+` or `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+`. That is, look for one-or-more characters followed by one-or-more digits. Which regex is it? bash? pcre? grep? awk?

Comment: `example\d{3}` - looks for example and exactly 3 digits

Comment: In which language are you wotking on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my exact problem, I should have included this into the question but I needed to remove instances of `width="xxx"`

I figured out the regex as `/width="[0-9][0-9][0-9]"/g`

Comment: @Scordo Yeh that's simpler though I understand mine.

Answer (score 0):

use `d{3}` for 3 numbers, so the whole regex shoule be:

```
/\w+\d{3}/g
```

http://regexr.com/v1/?38lcq

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your digits will always be at the end, this regex should work for you: `([^\s]+?\d{3})/g` since it will match any non white space character which is followed by 3 digits.

If this were not to be the case (you have no idea where, in the string, will the digits show up) then we have a bit of a problem since we would need to define a pattern for all 3 possible cases:

1. Digits are in the middle of the sub string.
   2  Digits are at the beginning of the sub string.
2. Digits are at the end of the sub string.

This would result in the creation of something like so: `(([^\s]+?\d{3}[^\s]+?)|(\d{3}[^\s]+?)|([^\s]+?\d{3}))/g`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove three digits and everything which are not spaces from the left and from the right

```
echo 'this is an example536 string with 2 example725' | sed 's/[^[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]\{3\}[^[:space:]]*//g'
```

Comment: That example isn't *just* regex as requested. I have no idea what language that is.

Comment: It is bash script. You can test it in linux command line. You have not said which language you will use. It is not a regex who removes strings, you need a tool. sed is such a tool. The actual regex is [^[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]\{3\}[^[:space:]]* .

Answer (score 0):

If it's PHP, a replace will do it:

```
$s = "this is an example536 string with 2 example725"
$r = preg_replace('/\w+[\d]+ ?/', '', $s);
//outputs: this is an string with 2
```

The general regex to match what you want is.

```
/\w+[\d]+/
```